# Common regex to match patterns Gig1/2 and Gig1/2/3

Tags: java, regex

What is the common regex to match below patterns?

- `Gig1/2`
- `Gig1/2/3`

I am having the below pattern to match the strings Gig1/1 and Gig1/1/1.
But the issue is,Gig1/1/1 is matching with both patterns.Please let me know ,how to avoid this?

Pat1 : ".*?(\d+)/(\d+)"

Pat2 : ".*?(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)"

Comment: Is the pattern you are looking for: `Gig/number/number` or `Gig/number/number/number` ?

Comment: Hm `"Pattern 1 : Gig1/2(/3)?"`? Please give more description on your pattern.

Comment: Is the first three characters always supposed to be 'Gig', or can they be anything?

Comment: What exactly do you want? A common regex for both patterns (as the title and first sentence of your question imply) or two separate regexes that only match one pattern each (as the last sentences implies)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pat1: `^\p{L}+(\d+)/(\d+)$`

Pat2: `^\p{L}+(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)$`

If you just apply `^.*?(\d+)/(\d+)$` to `Gig1/2/3`, the `.*?` part will match `Gig1/` since the dot can match any character (no difference whether it's lazy or not).

You need to be more specific about what may come before the numbers. I'm assuming letters, so I used `\p{L}` which means "any (Unicode) letter".

Don't forget to double the backslashes before pasting those regexes in a Java string.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add start and end anchors to your regex:

Pat1 : `^"\w+(\d+)/(\d+)"$`

Pat2 : `^"\w+(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)"$`

Comment: @JavaUser: it means repeat the previous thing atleast one time and at most two times.

Comment: <nitpick> It means the previous thing *appears* between one and two times.  "Repeats one or two times" implies two or three appearances, which isn't the case. </nitpick>

Comment: @codaddict: The lazy dot int Pat1 will expand to also match the string with three numbers.